how to display the values entered in one field in a view in different form as options of drop down in another field in different form in Lotus notes
how to display the values entered in one field in a view of a form as options of drop down in another field in different form but in Same database in Lotus notes.
I tried to create a hidden field which gets the values using @Unique(@Trim)) from the view and created another view which displays this data. But nothing seems to be working. I need this is formula. Not in lotus script

In choices of first field I used formula @DbColumn("":"NoCache";@DbName;"Project Details";1). Where project details is the view name, in first column i have project names, which are displaying as choices of drop down. And in second column of the same view I have manager names of the respected projects. First Column name as Projects, second column as Managers. Now based on the selected project I need to display that ManagerName in the ManagerName field. @If( ProjectName=""; "": @DbLookup("";""; @DbName; "Project Details"; ProjectName 2; [FailSilent])) in this field isworking after saving only.

@Per Henrik Lausten I want the ManagerName to display on selecting the ProjectName from the list. ManagerName is the last field. The firmula I used is working only when I click on save. I trried to use different approach using LotusScript Onchange event. But didn't work. Could anyone please help.

You need to create a view that selects the documents created with the first form and add a column that displays values from the field in that form.
In the form with the drop-down, you need to select "Use formula for choices" and enter a formula using @DbColumn.  Specify the above-mentioned view and the appropriate column number in the arguments for @DbColumn. You can use @Unique, @Sort, and @Trim on the result of the @DbColumn before you return the list of values for the drop-down.

I want the ManagerName to display on selecting the ProjectName from the list. ManagerName is the last field. The firmula I used is working only when I click on save. I trried to use different approach using LotusScript Onchange event. But didn't work. Could anyone please help.

In choices of first field I used formula @DbColumn("":"NoCache";@DbName;"Project Details";1). Where project details is the view name, in first column i have project names, which are displaying as choices of drop down. And in second column of the same view I have manager names of the respected projects. First Column name as Projects, second column as Managers. Now based on the selected project I need to display that ManagerName in the ManagerName field. @If( ProjectName=""; "": @DbLookup("";""; @DbName; "Project Details"; ProjectName 2; [FailSilent])) in this field isworking after saving only.

There is a property that you can set on the first field called "Refresh fields on keyword change" that should trigger a refresh of the second field -- presuming that the second field is a computed field. This feature has been around for a very long time, so it should work... but unfortunately I have heard reports of some bugs related to it, so I'm just going to wish you good luck and hope it works for you.
